# Jquery Mobile disable style on a fixed header

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Hey all i am trying to disable to theme/style on a fixed header in the code below:

```
<div id="home-header" data-role="header" data-id="mobile-header" role="banner" 
 data-position="fixed" style="background-color: #FF8040; 
 class="ui-header ui-header-fixed slidedown" 
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000; 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000; box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000;">
    <span class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">
        Temp text here
    </span>
</div><!-- /Header -->
```

I've already tried using **data-role="none"** but that only messes up the fixed header (causes it to just float at the bottom of the screen). I have also tried to just take the *class=* out but it seems to automatically place that back into the code once the page is being redered.

Is there anyway to do this without messing up the normal operation for a fixed header in JMobile?

Thanks.

**update #1**

```
#home-header {
        background-color: #FF8040 !important; 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000 !important; 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000 !important; 
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000 !important;
}

<div id="home-header" data-role="header" data-id="mobile-header" data-position="fixed" role="banner">
    <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">
        Temp test here
    </h1>
</div><!-- /Header -->
```

**update #2**

```
.ui-bar-a {
        border: 1px solid #FFA346 !important;
        background: #FF8040 !important;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000 !important; 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000 !important; 
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #000000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/aJXXx/

Every css change in jQuery Mobile must be overriden with !important:

```
#home-header {
    background: none !important;
    text-shadow:  none !important;
    color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Hum... i did as your example is but it still shows the same theme? Check my OP for the updated code.

Comment: Impossible, I showed you a working example. Lets debug this, do you use 1 large HTMl page with multiple pages or multiple HTML's? This is important.

Comment: Be careful here .ui-bar-a will work only if you have data-theme set to a, do it like this: .ui-bar-a, .ui-bar-b, .ui-bar-c,.ui-bar-d, .ui-bar-e {.....} this will make sure it will work no matter what data-theme is set.